# PRNG, python. 1 button - 2 function?

Tags: python, tkinter, button, random, tkinter-button

help me please. It is necessary that when the 'Generate' button(`gen`) is pressed, 2 functions (`clicked1`, `gen1`) are executed. But it only run `clicked1`.

I read that I can use `lambda`; or create a separate function that includes the ones you need. But `gen1` still fails.
**but the most important thing is that**
when I removed `clicked1` from the code completely, then `gen1` didn't work either(

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *  
from tkinter import messagebox, scrolledtext
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar  
from tkinter import ttk   
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from random import randint

class App:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = tkinter.Tk()
        self.window.title("Генератор") 
        self.window['bg'] = '#FFF5EE'
        self.window.geometry('660x550') 
        self.window.resizable(False,False)

        self.lb1 = Label(self.window, text="Enter:", background='#FFF5EE', font = ("Comic Sans MS", 14))  
        self.lb1.grid(column=0, row=2) 

        self.lb2 = Label(self.window, text="min(1-999)",background='#FFF5EE', font = ("Comic Sans MS", 12))  
        self.lb2.grid(column=1, row=3) 

        self.lb3 = Label(self.window, text="max(1-999)", background='#FFF5EE', font = ("Comic Sans MS", 12))  
        self.lb3.grid(column=1, row=4) 

        self.lb4 = Label(self.window, text="amount of numbers", background='#FFF5EE', font = ("Comic Sans MS", 12))  
        self.lb4.grid(column=4, row=3)  

        self.txt2 = Entry(self.window,width=10, borderwidth=3)  
        self.txt2.grid(column=2, row=3)  

        self.txt3 = Entry(self.window,width=10, borderwidth=3)  
        self.txt3.grid(column=2, row=4) 

        self.txt4 = Entry(self.window,width=10, borderwidth=3)  
        self.txt4.grid(column=5, row=3)  

        self.scrolltxt = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.window, width=30, height=3, borderwidth=7, state='disabled')
        self.scrolltxt.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=3, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.image = Image.open("C:\\Users\\ПК\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\лб1\\11.png")
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)

        self.gen = Button(self.window, text="Generate", command = lambda:[self.clicked1(), self.gen1()])
        self.gen.grid(row=4, column=6)

        self.canvas = tkinter.Canvas(self.window, height=250, width=230)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=4)
        self.image = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw', image = self.photo)


        self.btn = Button(self.window, text="Delete", command=self.delete)  
        self.btn.grid(column=6, row=5)

        self.exit = Button(self.window, text="Exit", command=quit)
        self.exit.grid(column=6, row=6)

        self.window.mainloop()

    def clicked1(self):
        print("clicked1")
        self.image = Image.open("C:\\Users\\ПК\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\лб1\\22.png")  
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=4)
        self.image = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw',image=self.photo)

    def gen1(self):
        try:
                MinNum = int(self.txt2.get())
                MaxNum = int(self.txt3.get())
                Num = int(self.txt4.get())
        except ValueError:
                messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter correct numbers!")
        else:
                Nums = " "
                if MinNum <= MaxNum:
                        i = 0
                        while i < Num:
                                numOne = randint(MinNum, MaxNum)
                                Nums = Nums + ' ' + str(numOne)
                                i += 1
                        self.scrolltxt.delete(1.0, END) 
                        self.scrolltxt.insert(INSERT, str(Nums) + "\n") 
                else:
                        messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please enter correct numbers!")
        
    def delete(self):
        self.scrolltxt.delete(1.0, END)
        print("clicked1")
        self.image = Image.open("C:\\Users\\ПК\\OneDrive\\Рабочий стол\\лб1\\11.png")  
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.image)
        self.canvas.grid(row=0,column=4)
        self.image = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor='nw',image=self.photo)
    
app= App()
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong
I hope I explained the problem clearly

Comment: Note that it is `clicked1`, not `command1`.  Cannot reproduce the issue, both `clicked1()` and `gen1()` are executed when `Generate` button is clicked.

Comment: *"`gen1()` still fails"* - do you mean that nothing is inserted into the text box? It is because the text box is *disabled*.  You need to enable it before inserting text and disable it after.

Comment: @acw1668, I understood what you mean. but I don't quite understand how to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the `clicked1()` and `gen1()` are executed when the `Generate` button is clicked.  However nothing will be inserted into the text box because the text box is disabled.

You need to enable the text box before inserting text and disabled it back after:

```py
self.scrolltxt.config(state="normal") # enable the text box
self.scrolltxt.delete("1.0", END) # better use "1.0" instead of 1.0 
self.scrolltxt.insert(INSERT, str(Nums) + "\n")
self.scrolltxt.config(state="disabled") # disable the text box
```